# Giving nulls when top N is less than N

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So this is the deal, I have a bunch of raw data that I need to process and output through C# programmatically, for this I am using `SQL` to assign values to variables as it iterates over **"invoice numbers"**.

The invoice must include the description which is limited to 70 characters. I also only have 5 description fields I can fill.

some invoices have more than 5, others can have only 1.

so I've got this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT top 5

iw.Descript,
NEWID()
FROM staging.InputOrigin iw 


left join [Parameters].[VendorMasterUpdate] VMU ON VMU.article = iw.article AND iw.Country=vmu.origin 

WHERE post_advice='XXXXXXX' 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

And I'm using this to get the "top 5" random descriptions.

C# is assigning the variable as follows:

```
var Desc1 = table2.Rows[i]["Descript"];
```

Now I know i could parametize the i to check `rowscount` and if `rowscount` is less than 5, then to iterate `until i = rowscount` and everything above `rowscount` to have the description as `NULL`.

But I am looking in the opposite direction, which is how to do this on SQL.

Any way I can get `TOP 5` random and if this is less than 5, then to fill the extra values with `NULLS`?

Comment: The only reason `TOP 5` woukdn't bring back 5 rows is if there are less than 5 rows in the table. I assume, therefore, that's the problem and that the table won't also have "enough" rows?

Comment: Do a UNION ALL with five rows that are all null. Then use an outer query to do TOP 5 on the unioned query, ordered by the `NEWID` column (to ensure the `null` records are at the end). If the original query has 5 records - they'll be returned. If they don't, some of the null records will be part of the result. _To be clear though - this is a terrible idea. You should do this in C# instead._

Comment: @Larnu exactly, some invoices have more than 5, others can have only 1. Edited

Comment: what do you want all records for one invoice or just top 5 records for one invoice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a tally table (in this case just 5 values) and then a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT V.I,
       sq.Descript
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) V (i)
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 5 
                       iw.Descript,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RN
                FROM staging.InputOrigin iw
                     LEFT JOIN [parameters].[VendorMasterUpdate] VMU ON VMU.article = iw.article
                                                                    AND iw.Country = VMU.origin
                WHERE post_advice = 'XXXXXXX'
                GROUP BY iw.Descript) sq ON sq.RN = V.i;
```

Comment: I had thought about using a row_number but not over the NEWID. Elegant, I like this. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way would be:

```
With CTE as
(... my query...)
, CTE2 as
(
select *
from CTE
union all
select null, null, null -- 1
union all
select null, null, null -- 2
union all
select null, null, null -- 3
union all
select null, null, null -- 4
union all
select null, null, null -- 5
)
select top 5 * 
from CTE2
order by thenewidcolumn
```

Comment: nice new use for CTE. Thanks!